# Calling SetExecutionStrategy more than once

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to implement an entity framework configuration that deals with deadlocks and retries them. I already have a default execution strategy set in my MyConfiguration constructor. My question is, can I call one after the other, or will they override each other? I am not 100% confident with these so any information would be greatly appreciated.

If I use both in my MyConfiguration constructor, will they override each other or will they actually register both and therefore, both will work?

Here is the code:

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
        // Trims all strings coming from entity framework
        AddInterceptor(new StringTrimmerInterceptor());

        SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => SuspendExecutionStrategy
          ? (IDbExecutionStrategy)new DefaultExecutionStrategy()
          : new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());

        SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new MyCustomExecutionStrategy(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
    }

    public static bool SuspendExecutionStrategy
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool?)CallContext.LogicalGetData("SuspendExecutionStrategy") ?? false;
        }
        set
        {
            CallContext.LogicalSetData("SuspendExecutionStrategy", value);
        }
    }
}

public class StringTrimmerInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
{
    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace == DataSpace.SSpace)
        {
            var queryCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbQueryCommandTree;
            if (queryCommand != null)
            {
                var newQuery = queryCommand.Query.Accept(new StringTrimmerQueryVisitor());
                interceptionContext.Result = new DbQueryCommandTree(
                    queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                    queryCommand.DataSpace,
                    newQuery);
            }
        }
    }

    private class StringTrimmerQueryVisitor : DefaultExpressionVisitor
    {
        private static readonly string[] _typesToTrim = { "nvarchar", "varchar", "char", "nchar" };

        public override DbExpression Visit(DbNewInstanceExpression expression)
        {
            var arguments = expression.Arguments.Select(a =>
            {
                var propertyArg = a as DbPropertyExpression;
                if (propertyArg != null && _typesToTrim.Contains(propertyArg.Property.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name))
                {
                    return EdmFunctions.Trim(a);
                }

                return a;
            });
            return DbExpressionBuilder.New(expression.ResultType, arguments);
        }
    }
}

public static class SqlRetryErrorCodes
{
    public const int TimeoutExpired = -2;
    public const int Deadlock = 1205;
    public const int CouldNotOpenConnection = 53;
    public const int TransportFail = 121;
}

public class MyCustomExecutionStrategy : DbExecutionStrategy
{
    public MyCustomExecutionStrategy(int maxRetryCount, TimeSpan maxDelay) : base(maxRetryCount, maxDelay) { }

    private readonly List<int> _errorCodesToRetry = new List<int>
        {
            SqlRetryErrorCodes.Deadlock,
            SqlRetryErrorCodes.TimeoutExpired,
            SqlRetryErrorCodes.CouldNotOpenConnection,
            SqlRetryErrorCodes.TransportFail
        };

    protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception exception)
    {
        var sqlException = exception as SqlException;
        if (sqlException != null)
        {
            foreach (SqlError err in sqlException.Errors)
            {
                // Enumerate through all errors found in the exception.
                if (_errorCodesToRetry.Contains(err.Number))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this post](https://romiller.com/2013/08/19/ef6-suspendable-execution-strategy/) from a member of the .NET team it should override the strategy everytime you call it. The link shows that this can be changed during runtime even (on every ctor-call). In the usage section he states:

> Now we can use the flag to disable retry logic for certain operations.

So my (unproved) answer is: You can call it more than one time and it will always have the last set strategy configured.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Any suggestion to merge them to maintain both execution strategies?